# How to use PopSQL with Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I want to connect PopSQL editor with phpmyadmin database. I have xmapp installed in my computer. PopSQL looks better to me for practicing mySQL.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not a Database server. PHPMyAdmin is just a web based client interface used to connect to your MySQL server and manage databases etc

Comment: So, how to use PopSQL?

Comment: Follow the steps here: https://popsql.io/docs/getting-started/connecting-to-your-database/